# In Rock paper scissors, rock is scissors' "Kryptonite", scissors are "what" to rock?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm trying to find a word for something that always beats something else. *Kryptonite* might be used for something that you always lose to. From *Superman*, of course.

e.g. Rock is scissors' kryptonite (scissors lose to rock). Water is fire's krytonite (fire loses to water), and so on.

I want to know the opposite word of this "kryptonite". Say between rock and scissors. What word would be appropriate here:

Scissors are rock's _____. Fire is water's _____.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, I do not have an answer

Comment: Do you have a real example you were considering applying this to, other than rock papers scissors?

Comment: Maybe worth noting that calling something that is antithetical to something else 'Kryptonite' is severely informal and possibly unlikely to be understood by people who have not read Superman comics, or pleasing to those who don't like them.

Comment: I was making (programming)objects out of these three: rock, paper, scissors for the game of the same name. Each of them would have two main properties. One has the value of ~"the thing that it loses to" -- I named this property "krytonite". The other property is "the thing that it beats". Didn't know how to name it. I wondered if such word existed. Hence the question. :)

Comment: If Rock is the kryptonite, then Scissors must be the Superman, of course. :P

Comment: My vote goes to "the Jimmy Olsen".

Answer (score 3):

Running the risk of posting something corny: Anti-Kryptonite, first used in *Adventure Comics*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What does Superman always lose to? Kryptonite!
What or who always loses to Superman? Lex Luthor, Mxyxplital (sp), Lois Lane, Crime.

Answer (score 0):

It's been years. But something antithetical is the opposition to the fact. Such as ice is antithetical to fire. Elemental oppositions such as shown in pokemon are a great example of this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Nemesis** (n.)

OED

> **1.b. Originally and chiefly North American. In extended use: a persistent tormentor; a long-standing rival, an arch-enemy**.
>
> 1933 Antonio Melendrez, nemesis of William Walker in Baja California. *J. M. Mitchell in Calif. Hist. Society Quarterly vol. 12 318* (title)
>
> 1975 Juan Pablo Perez Alfonzo.., long-time nemesis of the oil companies. *Business Week 13 January 78/3*